# Sales order stuck on "processing"

Tags: order-status

An order made a few days ago is stuck on "processing". They payment has been captured and shows up on our merchant account. I've searched for questions previously asked and the answers always seem very complex as I am not familiar with code. Is there an easy fix for this or will I be paying our website support for help in fixing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at magento Order Workflow, a order will remain in the processing until it is ship (If your order is not invoice then you will not be able to complete the order until it is invoice)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. It goes through our inventory system which shows the order but with no item and no payment, so it must be a problem on that end.

Answer (score 1):

Has the order been invoiced? Depending on how your Magento installation is set up, you could invoice the order and choose "capture offline" to complete the order, if that is what's holding up the status change.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, go to the order and down in the comments, set the status to "In Production". If you are lucky, it will just jump to completed.  I had an order placed for some free downloadable products and the product was misconfigured to be a virtual product. Magento got confused because it didn't know what steps to take to go from a $0 payment and No shipping for something that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Still works as of 8-9-2016.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with an order that had paypal a express payment, we had the payment gateway set up wrong and it was set to manually authorize payment/capture the payment in paypal.

I went to paypal, captured payment, shipped the order and figured it would go to complete, but about a week later I saw it was still processing.

To fix this as noted above I needed to invoice the order in Magento, and near the bottom right it gives capture options. I set the option to **capture offline** and it went to complete after submitting the invoice.

I tried both other options: Capture online produces a payment gateway error along the lines of "payment already captured by payment gateway", and the other "dont capture" or whatever it says also leaves the order in processing limbo.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem occurred somewhere in the capture payment part of the invoicing process. I had invoiced and shipped the order but it was still showing as "processing"

To identify the problem I did the following
1. View the order
2. Click Invoices (on the left ORDER VIEW menu)
3. Clicked View on the invoice
4. Clicked Capture

This is when it threw the error (which I feel was incorrect as Paypal was setup correctly)

To resolve the issue I did the following
5. Clicked cancel to cancel the invoice
6. Back at the order screen I clicked invoice to invoice the order
7. At the bottom of the invoice screen I selected manual capture
8. Completed the invoice (without emailing customer)

Then my order showed as completed.

Hope that helps